# How do you write in Robot Framework a dynamic element with multiple identifiers?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework as well as writing automation using Pycharm and have run into an issue I cannot find an answer to. I have text boxes that the uid changes every time a change is made to the page. I have tried using an xpath but all of the text boxes appear to have the same starting ID of 56$551056-- so i cannot use  xpath=//input[contains(@id='56$551056--')] without trying to add something additional to it.
Example TextBox1

```html
<input type="text" class="gwt-TextBox WNN2" data-automation-id="textInputBox" tabindex="0" role="textbox" id="56$551056--uid74-input" dir="ltr" aria-invalid="false" xpath="1">
```

Example TextBox2

```html
<input type="text" class="gwt-TextBox WNN2" data-automation-id="textInputBox" tabindex="0" role="textbox" id="56$551056--uid75-input" dir="ltr" aria-invalid="false" xpath="1">
```

There are 3-5 boxes in each section I am automating and they all seem to have the exact same code except for the uid.  Removing ID and Class name (as these both throw a warning in ChroPath of being dynamic just gives me a string of //div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//li[2]//div[2]//div[1]//div[1]

Any help or direction on this greatly appreciated.
Update
So I have these paths connecting the ID and the Label but I would have to remove uid100 as this is the part that continues to change on the page. I have tried several different combinations to get this to work in RF but I cannot seem to get it exactly right. //label[@id='56$551056--uid100-formLabel'] //div[contains(text(),'First Name')] //*[@id="56$551056--uid100-input"]

```html
<li class="WDSO WOTO" role="presentation" data-automation-id="formLabelRequired"><div class="WFSO WIRO"><label id="56$551056--uid430-formLabel" data-automation-id="formLabel" for="56$551056--uid430-input">First Name</label><div class="WISO wd-74ef43c8-48bb-445c-9b49-1a788d7c4b10" aria-hidden="true">First Name</div></div><div data-automation-id="decorationWrapper" id="56$551056" class="WJSO"><div class="WOAJ"><div class="WHN2 textInput WGN2 WJ5" data-automation-id="textInput" id="56$551056--uid430" data-metadata-id="56$551056" style="visibility: visible;"><input type="text" class="gwt-TextBox WON2" data-automation-id="textInputBox" tabindex="0" role="textbox" id="56$551056--uid430-input" dir="ltr" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true"></div></div></div></li>
```

Comment: Do you have the ability to ask the developers to add more identifying information, such as a custom class name or some other attribute (eg: `data-qa`)? That would be the best solution. Also, are the input elements just floating in space, or are they associated with a unique label, div, or span?

Comment: I dont as this is part of the Workday application. There is a label set above the entry box which I tried to implement into it but it is completely separate from the actual text box     //label[contains(text(),'First Name')]

Comment: @BryanOakley IMO, developers can't help much as the application is `gwt` based.

Comment: @micheich Update the question with the `<input>` tags along with the `<label>` tags.

Comment: @DebanjanB: the developers should have the ability to add any extra attributes they want.

Comment: @BryanOakley GWT is a readymade Java based library to build websites. You just need to integrate it :) Making changes from application development perspective would be tough. The `GWT` library services are offered on demand basis.

Comment: @DebanjanB Apologies this is my first post on here. I think I added them as comments. Updating the questions now with what I think you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to insert `item label` into your xpath instead of `id`. For example, if your textbox having the label **Customer Name**, then something will be like:

//label[text()='Customer Name']`/../../`input

(The dark part is my assumption)

So, you could get rid of the annoying dynamic ID

Please provide your full HTML, so I could give a better answer

Comment: I added HTML to the original question. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @micheich This one should work for you: `//label[text()='First Name']/../following-sibling::div//input`

Comment: Thank you! It was the following sibling part that I wasnt getting correct.

Comment: @micheich Please learn about Xpath Axes, it will help you much in such scenarios like this

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to work with the developers to provide unique attributes for each input element.

If you can't do that, and if you can't easily uniquely identify an input element, then find the nearest element that you can uniquely identify, and use that as a base for finding the input element.

For example, if the input element is associate with a label -- and most are -- you can use the label element as part of the xpath. For example, `//label[@text='First Name']//input`. Exactly how you do that depends on the structure of the page - the input element might be the first sibling, or the first child, or some element elsewhere in the DOM but pointed to by an attribute in the label (eg: `<label for= "56$551056--uid74-input">`)

This question isn't unique to robot framework, it's common to just about every test automation framework.

Answer (score 0):

Find the element by using xpath locators using the reference to parent element of the following element

```
<input type="text" class="gwt-TextBox WNN2" data-automation-id="textInputBox" tabindex="0" role="textbox" id="56$551056--uid74-input" dir="ltr" aria-invalid="false" xpath="1">
```

xpath example would be as follows:

```
xpath of parent//input[contains(@class,'TextBox')]
```